# SSDT: Schema compare script generator issues

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I am using VS 2017 to do a schema compare between a SQLPROJ and a database hosted on sql server 2017.

When I exclude everything that is not needed between the 2 schemas, I generate a scipt. My data tools tells me that the script generated successfully but does not give me a url for the script. it also generates in 2 seconds as compared to when a script ACTUALLY successfully generates which takes anywhere between 5 and 20 minutes.

I did notice that some of my exclusions weren't completely grayed out. is this an issue? or is the issue that I am comparing a V2017 database against a schema generally used for 2016 and below?

I tried using VS 2013 and 2015 but neither of them worked either.

Answer (score 0):

The script gets generated in "**%temp%**" folder. You can go to "**run**" (i.e. **Win + R**) and type "**%temp%**" and it will open the folder.

The path would be something like: `C:\Users\Testuser\AppData\Local\Temp\41`

Once you are inside the folder you will find the file as **Microsoft SQL Server Query File**(type)

> If it doesn't work, restart the machine and try again